# Using CKEditor 5 with nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor, nuxt.js

I'm trying to import a custom build of CKEditor 5 in my Nuxtjs project and I've been tried every possible way to import it correctly but none of them worked for me and this is one of them:

```
let ClassicEditor
    let CKEditor

    if (process.client) {
      ClassicEditor = require('./../../static/js/ckeditor')
      CKEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue')
    }else{
      CKEditor = { component : {template:'<div></div>'}}
    }
```

```
  data() {
    return {
         editor: ClassicEditor,
   }
}
```

```
  components:{
ckeditor: CKEditor.component
  },
```

```
<client-only><ckeditor :editor="editor" /></client-only>
```

Every time I change the way a different error appears, for example, `Window is not Defined` and when i use different way shows a different error so I want to know what is the most correct way to use CKEditor with Nuxtjs in universal mode, consider that i haven't done anything and help me with the correct way starting from the installation

Answer (score 2):

try this

npm install --save @blowstack/ckeditor-nuxt

Comment: I used this package but inserting the image does not work, how to upload the image to the server, is there a sample code for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use by importing the package on client side.

Create `Editor.vue` components

```
<template>
  <ckeditor
    :editor="editor"
    :config="editorConfig"
  />
</template>
<script>
let ClassicEditor
let CKEditor

if (process.client) {
  ClassicEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic')
  CKEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue2')
} else {
  CKEditor = { component: { template: '<div></div>' } }
}
export default {
  components: {
    ckeditor: CKEditor.component
  },
  data () {
    return {
      editor: ClassicEditor,
      editorConfig: {}
    }
}
</script>
```

Usage:

```
<client-only placeholder="Loading Text Editor...">
  <editor v-model="textInput"/>
</client-only>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### window is not defined

If you set `ssr: true` in the `nuxt.config.js` and put your custom `VCKEditor.vue` into the components folder, the Nuxt will scan the components folder by Server Side and it doesn't know the `window` keyword which is the JavaScript object in `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue2`.

You can see more about [components doc](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/components/#components-discovery).

I don't like use the `process.client` to check ssr mode.

I have two solutions, just choose one

- set `components: false` in the `nuxt.config.js`.
- Move the your custom `VCKEditor.vue` to components folder outside.

Finally, register custom `VCKEditor.vue` as plugins and set plugins `ssr: false` in the `nuxt.config.js`.

Here is the [sample project](https://github.com/changemyminds/nuxtjs-integrate-ckeditor5).

The code snippet

- nuxt.config.js

```js
const path = require('path')
const CKEditorWebpackPlugin = require("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin")
const CKEditorStyles = require("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils").styles

export default {
  // ignore other settings...

  ssr: true,
   
  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    {
      src: '~/plugins/ckeditor.js', ssr: false
    },
  ],
   
  // set false to disable scan the components folder
  components: false,
 
  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    transpile: [/ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]src[/\\].+\.js$/],

    plugins: [
      // If you set ssr: true that will cause the following error. This error does not affect the operation.
      // ERROR  [CKEditorWebpackPlugin] Error: No translation has been found for the zh language.
      new CKEditorWebpackPlugin({
        // See https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/ui-language.html
        language: "zh",
        additionalLanguages: 'all',
        addMainLanguageTranslationsToAllAssets: true,
      })
    ],

    // If you don't add postcss, the CKEditor css will not work.
    postcss: CKEditorStyles.getPostCssConfig({
      themeImporter: {
        themePath: require.resolve("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark")
      },
      minify: true
    }),

    extend(config, ctx) {
      // If you do not exclude and use raw-loader to load svg, the following errors will be caused.
      // Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
      const svgRule = config.module.rules.find(item => {
        return /svg/.test(item.test);
      })
      svgRule.exclude = [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '@ckeditor')];

      // add svg to load raw-loader
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
        use: ["raw-loader"]
      })
    }
  }
}
```

- components/editor/VCKEditor.vue

```js
<template>
  <ckeditor
    v-model="editorData"
    :editor="editor"
    :config="editorConfig"
  ></ckeditor>
</template>

<script>
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue2'
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor'

import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold'
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic.js'
import Underline from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/underline'
import Strikethrough from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/strikethrough'

// less Heading + Essentials plugin can't input the text
import Heading from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading'
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials'

import ImageUpload from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageupload'
import ImageInsert from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageinsert'
import AutoImage from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/autoimage'
import Image from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image'
import ImageResizeEditing from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageresize/imageresizeediting'
import ImageResizeHandles from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageresize/imageresizehandles'
import Base64UploadAdapter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/src/adapters/base64uploadadapter'

export default {
  name: 'VCKEditor',
  components: { ckeditor: CKEditor.component },
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    editorData: {
      get() {
        return this.value
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit('input', value)
      },
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      editor: ClassicEditor,
      editorConfig: {
        plugins: [
          Bold,
          Italic,
          Underline,
          Strikethrough,
          Heading,
          Essentials,
          ImageUpload,
          ImageInsert,
          AutoImage,
          Image,
          ImageResizeEditing,
          ImageResizeHandles,
          Base64UploadAdapter,
        ],

        toolbar: {
          items: [
            'heading',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'underline',
            'strikethrough',
            '|',
            'insertImage',
          ],
        },
        language: 'zh',
      },
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

- plugins/ckeditor.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VCKEditor from "../components/editor/VCKEditor.vue";

Vue.component('v-ckeditor', VCKEditor);
```

- pages/index.vue

```js
<template>
  <client-only>
    <v-ckeditor v-model="text" />
  </client-only>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      text: 'Hello World!!',
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @blowstack/ckeditor-nuxt package.
Here is editor config for uploader.
Use @blowstack/ckeditor-nuxt package.
Here is editor config for uploader.

```
editorConfig: {
  
        simpleUpload: {
          uploadUrl: `${process.env.apiUrl}/api/console/uploads/single_file`,
          headers: {
            authorization: `Bearer ${_.get(
              this.$store,
              "state.agency.global.token"
            )}`,
          },
        },
        removePlugins: ["Title"],
      }
```

Response data from upload API like this:

```
{
   url: ".../image.png"
}
```

Refs: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/upload-adapter.html#passing-additional-data-to-the-response

```
editorConfig: {
  
        simpleUpload: {
          uploadUrl: `${process.env.apiUrl}/api/console/uploads/single_file`,
          headers: {
            authorization: `Bearer ${_.get(
              this.$store,
              "state.agency.global.token"
            )}`,
          },
        },
        removePlugins: ["Title"],
      }
```