# How to use CKEditor with Nuxt.js - window is not defined error

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

In Vue.js, this is the setup I used. In Nuxt.js I am getting a "Window is not defined" error.

From my research, it looks like I have to turn SSR off for this, and perhaps use a plugin setup. But I wasn't able to get it working like that.

But I am not quite sure how to go about it. I tried a couple examples around the web, but none of them worked.

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

```
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue'
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor'
import EssentialsPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials'
import AutoformatPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat/src/autoformat'
import HeadingPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading'
import BoldPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold'
import ItalicPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic'
import UnderlinePlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/underline'
import StrikethroughPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/strikethrough'
import SubscriptPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/subscript'
import SuperscriptPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/superscript'
import LinkPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link'
import ParagraphPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph'
import AlignmentPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment'
import ListPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list'

export default {
    name: 'Contents',
    components: {
        ckeditor: CKEditor.component
    },
    data() {
        return {
            updated_since_last_save: false,
            last_build_type: '',
            last_parent: '',
            editor: ClassicEditor,
            editorConfig: {
                plugins: [
                    EssentialsPlugin,
                    AutoformatPlugin,
                    HeadingPlugin,
                    BoldPlugin,
                    ItalicPlugin,
                    UnderlinePlugin,
                    StrikethroughPlugin,
                    SubscriptPlugin,
                    SuperscriptPlugin,
                    LinkPlugin,
                    ParagraphPlugin,
                    AlignmentPlugin,
                    ListPlugin
                ],
                toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'heading',
                        'bold',
                        'italic',
                        'underline',
                        'strikethrough',
                        'subscript',
                        'superscript',
                        'link',
                        'undo',
                        'redo',
                        'alignment',
                        'bulletedList',
                        'numberedList'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

I have added the `<client-only>` tags around the ckeditor component in the template. I still get the same error. Then I tried doing this:

adding `plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/ckeditor', mode: 'client' }],` to `nuxt.config.js`.

And I added a plugin file called `ckeditor.js` which contains

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue'
Vue.use(CKEditor)
```

Then I have just changed the first line in my imports inside my page:

```
import CKEditor from 'ckeditor'
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor'
import EssentialsPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials'
import AutoformatPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat/src/autoformat'
import HeadingPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading'
import BoldPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold'
import ItalicPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic'
import UnderlinePlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/underline'
import StrikethroughPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/strikethrough'
import SubscriptPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/subscript'
import SuperscriptPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/superscript'
import LinkPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link'
import ParagraphPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph'
import AlignmentPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment'
import ListPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list'

export default {
    name: 'Contents',
    components: {
        ckeditor: CKEditor.component
    },
    data() {
        return {
            updated_since_last_save: false,
            last_build_type: '',
            last_parent: '',
            editor: ClassicEditor,
            editorConfig: {
                plugins: [
                    EssentialsPlugin,
                    AutoformatPlugin,
                    HeadingPlugin,
                    BoldPlugin,
                    ItalicPlugin,
                    UnderlinePlugin,
                    StrikethroughPlugin,
                    SubscriptPlugin,
                    SuperscriptPlugin,
                    LinkPlugin,
                    ParagraphPlugin,
                    AlignmentPlugin,
                    ListPlugin
                ],
                toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'heading',
                        'bold',
                        'italic',
                        'underline',
                        'strikethrough',
                        'subscript',
                        'superscript',
                        'link',
                        'undo',
                        'redo',
                        'alignment',
                        'bulletedList',
                        'numberedList'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And I am getting the same error and also this:

```
This dependency was not found: 
* ckeditor in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/admin/contents/_project_id/_id.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
```

Comment: Import ckeditor package on client side. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69985388/10567990

Answer (score 2):

You have to surround your component with the **`client-only`** component so that nuxt understands that that component needs to be rendered only on the client side.

[docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-client-only/)

Comment: I have followed those docs to the best of my ability. (Just now). And I am now getting an error 'Cannot find module 'ckeditor''. I am probably doing the plugin thing wrong, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ckeditor.js:

```
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue'
export default defineNuxtPlugin(({ vueApp }) => {
  vueApp.use(CKEditor)
})
```