# Nuxt3: How to configure CKEditor 5 properly

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, ckeditor, nuxt3

Anyone know how I can properly configure CKEditor-5 in nuxt3 app. I am facing the issue which you can see below. I will also provide the code implementation.

Here's my current implementation

```html
<template>
  <div
    class="field"
    :class="{ 'form-group--error': props.error, active: text.length !== 0 }"
  >
    <CKEditor
      v-model="text"
      dir="rtl"
      :editor="ClassicEditor"
      :config="config"
      :tag-name="props.tagName"
      :disabled="props.disabled"
      @input="$emit('input', text)"
    />
    <label class="required" :placeholder="props.label">{{ props.label }}</label>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script setup>
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue";
import "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/translations/ar";

const props = defineProps({
  value: { type: String, required: false, default: "" },
  tagName: { type: String, required: false, default: "div" },
  disabled: { type: Boolean, required: false },
  uploadUrl: { type: String, required: false, default: "" },
  label: { type: String, required: false, default: "" },
  error: { type: Boolean, default: false },
});

const config = ref({
  language: "ar",
});
const text = ref("");

watch(props.value, () => {
  text.value = props.value;
});
</script>
```

It will give this error. Should I need to create a nuxt3 plugin for this if yes then please let me know how.

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue with it. I am unsure what is going on but I switch to TipTap. It is easier. I found this on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/Nuxt/comments/128wd5c/what_is_the_best_wysiwyg_basic_editor_for_nuxt_3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your CKEditor component inside the `<client-only>` tags. This worked for me.
For reference, this question: [How to use CKEditor with Nuxt.js - window is not defined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61528633/how-to-use-ckeditor-with-nuxt-js-window-is-not-defined-error)